# Responsive web design not working on iphone even with meta viewport

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, responsive-design

For some reason, the responsive website I'm building works on Android devices and when I resize the window, but not when its on an iPhone. I did include the 
         `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;" />`
 in my head section. Are there any possible reasons for this? Thanks!

```
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device width">
<title>Bruin Bash 2015</title>
<link rel="icon" href="images/BB-FAVICON.jpg"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flipclock.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: You should remove `minimum-scale` declaration

Comment: Add the simplified HTML code to your question, just seeing your viewport tag alone doesn't help much

Answer (score 0):

First of all, replace:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device width">
```

with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

We can't tell you more with only this piece of code, sir.